# Adding a TableViewController to an existing project

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, sdk, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an existing TableViewController as follows

```
// TableViewController.h

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController { NSArray *dataArray; }
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataArray;
```

And a navAppDelegate - to be specific:

```
// navAppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface navwAppDelegate : NSObject 
<UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;


// navAppDelegate.m
#import "navAppDelegate.h"

@implementation navigationtableviewAppDelegate
@synthesize window, navigationController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{    
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
}
```

Now, I simply added the files to an existing project, except I put the content of (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching{} in a (void)viewDidLoad{} since it's a view from now on and not a window (right?). It doesn't work and my guess is that I have to change all the window calls from above to a view? What am I making here fundamentally wrong? 
I'm making a call from

```
// StartOffHere.m

- (void)LetsGoButtonTouched {
navAppDelegate *newview = [[navAppDelegate alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; // I get a SIGABRT here
[[self navigationController] pushViewController: newview animated: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)LetsGoButtonTouched {
TableViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tableViewController animated: YES];
}
```

Try that. Is that what you wanted to happen?

If so, what I have done is created a new instance of your table view controller and pushed that. In your original code, you were trying to push on the app delegate which cannot be done; the app delegate is not  a view controller. TableViewController, your subclass of UITableViewController, is though, so you can use this for the pushViewController: method - and the table view will appear on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Benjamin. Excellent. But it didn't work quite that way though - after two hard days I managed it to run. For those who are interesed, here's what I did:

1. If you want to add an existing TableViewController with a NavigationController you'll only need the TableViewController and the DetailViewController files. Forget the AppDelegate.
2. Do twice new file -> Subclass and copy your existing code into identical TableViewController .h/.m/.xib - and DetailViewController .h/.m/.xib respectively.
3. When you make the method call you have to integrate both the TableViewController and the NavigationController - like this:

   ```
   - (void)LetsGoButtonTouched {
   TableViewController *tvc = [[[TableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc]autorelease];
   [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
   ```

By the way, this question gave me the hint:
[Add a UINavigationBar to a UITableViewController without a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035370/add-a-uinavigationbar-to-a-uitableviewcontroller-without-a-uinavigationcontroller)