# Objective-C: how to set keywindow to different viewcontroller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using storyboards and this code but nothing is appearing in my current `viewConntroller` but is in my first `viewConntroller`. Can anybody eli me set the `keywindow` to the current view i am on?

Here is the code i am using to show my `UINavigationBar`

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:bar];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you dont set the Viewcontroller to a Window

you need to do something like this:

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    //self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

this is how you add a uinavigationcontroller:

[Add a UINavigationBar to a UITableViewController without a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035370/add-a-uinavigationbar-to-a-uitableviewcontroller-without-a-uinavigationcontrolle)

if you want to present a new view controller

you simply use presentModalViewcontroller:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationcontroller vc animated:YES];
```

// I have written it all down just check the case and use it